# How to get pyomo VarData/values from slice of indexed variable?

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm working with pyomo variables indexed by multiple sets. I've created slices along some sets and would like to use these slices to access the variable values, given indices of the sliced-along sets.

Code that I hoped would work is:

```py
from pyomo.environ import *

m = ConcreteModel()
m.time = Set(initialize=[1,2,3])
m.space = Set(initialize=[1,2,3])
m.comp = Set(initialize=['a','b','c'])
m.v = Var(m.time, m.space, m.comp, initialize=1)
slice = m.v[:, :, 'a']
for x in m.space:
    value_list = []
    for t in m.time:
        value_list.append(slice[t, x].value)
        # write value_list to csv file
```

But this gives me:

```py
>>> value_list
[<pyomo.core.base.indexed_component_slice._IndexedComponent_slice object at 0x7f4db9104a58>, <pyomo.core.base.indexed_component_slice._IndexedComponent_slice object at 0x7f4db9104a58>, <pyomo.core.base.indexed_component_slice._IndexedComponent_slice object at 0x7f4db9104a58>]
```

instead of a list of values, as I hoped.

Is it possible to access values corresponding to variables slices from only the wildcard indices?

I tried using some of the methods of _IndexedComponent_slice, without success. For example:

```py
>>> for item in slice.wildcard_items(): item
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rparker1/Idaes/pyomo/pyomo/core/base/indexed_component_slice.py", line 194, in <genexpr>
    return ((_iter.get_last_index_wildcards(), _) for _ in _iter)
  File "/home/rparker1/Idaes/pyomo/pyomo/core/base/indexed_component_slice.py", line 350, in __next__
    _comp = _comp.__getitem__( _call[1] )
AttributeError: '_GeneralVarData' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I would expect some method to give me a dictionary mapping wildcard indices to vardata objects, but could not find one. Any help finding such a dictionary or other solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`_IndexedComponent_slice` objects are a bit tricky, in that they are designed to work with hierarchical models.  As such, they should be thought of as more of a special iterator and not as a view into a dictionary.  In particular, these "slice-like" objects defer the resolution of `__getitem__`, `__getattr__`, and `__call__` until *iteration time*.  So, when you say `slice.value`, that attribute lookup doesn't actually occur until you iterate over the slice.

The easiest way to get the variable values is to iterate over the slice:

```
value_list = list(m.v[:, :, 'a'].value)
```

If you want a new component that you can treat in a dictionary-like manner (just like the original `Var`), then you want to create a `Reference` component using the slice:

```
r = Reference(m.v[:, :, 'a'])
```

These can be attached to a model like any other component, and (for regular slices) will adopt the `ctype` of the referred-to objects (so in this case, `r` will look and act just like a `Var`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've implemented this using `Reference` components. Out of curiosity, how does deferring action until iteration time allow these objects to work better with hierarchical models?

Comment: Deferring resolution enables us to support a "chained slice notation".  Consider a model with an indexed Block `b` that contains an indexed Var `x`.  This supports syntax like `for v in model.b[:].x[:]:` or `model.b[:].x[:].fix(0)`